# remove matching phrase from beginning of list file and write changes

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a big list of domains and some start with "www." eg

```
www.google.com  
www.ebay.com  
twitter.com  
www.facebook.com
```

I would like to find and cut the beginning of lines that start with www.

eg `www.google.com` becomes `google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
 sed -i 's/^www\.//' file
```

Using `awk`:

```
 awk '{gsub("^www\\.", "");print}' file
```

Comment: The `g`s seem superfluous here (a pattern can't be both global AND anchored)?